# How to merge 2 windows in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, firefox-quantum

How can i merge 2 windows in Firefox Quantum, i.e. move all tabs of these 2 windows to 1 window?

I have many Firefox windows open and want to merge 2 of them. So far Web searches merely turn up extensions like these ([1](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/merge-window/), [2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/merge-all-windows/)) which seem to merge **all** windows. I have been looking at the [API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/move) but can't figure out how to use these functions from the script console (it says "ReferenceError: browser is not defined").

Comment: I [requested this feature](https://github.com/jonathanKingston/merge-windows/issues/1) and offered a donation.  Please join me and express your support there if you would also like to see it.

Comment: This can now be done natively in Firefox.  See update to DrMoishe Pippik's answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Easiest might be just to drag-and-drop tabs from one instance of Firefox onto the other. That gives you control of which tabs to move and in what order they appear.

A multiple tab selection feature was added to Firefox in version 64.  If you have a large number of tabs to move and want to do it in bulk, select the first tab, then shift-select the last tab to select the entire range (you can also Ctrl-select individual tabs to create a collection of selected tabs).  Then drag the lot to the other window.  So moving all tabs from one window to the other can be done with three mouse clicks.

Comment: Yes, i have enough tabs open to make this inconvenient, so am hoping for a programmatic method to merge windows.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I updated this for the new feature.  It was already the right answer.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234, Thanks for the edit. +1

Comment: Thanks, the multiple selection works for me!

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox you have an extension:

- [Merge-window](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/merge-window/)

and for Chrome I'd been using for years:

- [JoinTabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jointabs/bjmimocndihpmdoelbiilpkkfkppikap)

Comment: Alas, merge-window merges **all** windows, not merely 2 given windows.

Comment: Yes, both of these extensions merge all tabs scattered trough all windows into a single window